# What are "with MSDN" and "MSDN embedded" in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: license, visual-studio-2010

My company will buy a `Visual Studio 2010` licence.
But our 3rd party company suggests 2 options:

> Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 with MSDN
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 MSDN
>   embedded

They are same price.

Which one is better? Which one we should prefer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking into this [link](http://www.microsoft.com/presspass/press/2009/mar09/03-30VS08ProPR.mspx) on Microsoft's website, it would seem that the extras provided in MSDN Embedded would be useless if you or your company does not have developers. If you are looking to develop, then having MSDN Embedded would be highly beneficial.

The MSDN Embedded only allows you to have the embedded version of software and the newest updates so that the developers can help make Microsoft better. It will obviously allow you to have access to the MSDN (regular) software also.

-Hope this helps